# How did I contract Skeeyah.A!bit

Tags: windows-10, virus, trojan

Windows Defender just informed me it had placed the trojan `Win32/Skeeyah.A!bit` in quarantine. It was first found yesterday and now again today. How did I contract that? My download history reveals nothing noteworthy imho:

- A PDF file via Windows 10 Mail app (9 days ago)
- [verysleepy-cs-0.90.exe](https://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com/releases/7551837/0cba2c98-9db9-11e4-8488-c53bde01623f.exe?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAISTNZFOVBIJMK3TQ%2F20160901%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20160901T190011Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=7e3ca751d6afa57ad4cf7d53bd065ccfe04ea7a422bf92ce8e903a656e45b4c2&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=160303&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dverysleepy-cs-0.90.exe&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream) (13 days ago)
- A Visual Studio 2015 plugin, [HideMenu](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bdbcffca-32a6-4034-8e89-c31b86ad4813/file/18183/3/HideMenu.vsix) (14 days ago)
- MineCraft [installer](https://launcher.mojang.com/download/MinecraftInstaller.msi) (17 days ago)
- A Word .docx which I opened in OpenOffice Writer (23 days ago)
- [camstudio.exe](http://www.giftcapitalbyte.com/ScoI4OQ8skRLtkpA2zbHE4YE0yAW8gY2FKBxb3w3XJHDIKlqRr_W+B5LLdOeayFCRaQPBkWikuaRi9QVgBWA7MqxPLA9Cumiyw7WBK4kZGeiIiFFj6ne1+nzmoJ6sciramTxZ1_ZTZSLsrMc4DN2an6y9M1DjWpJQfbpwcK+Z0GjR15cnLZ6SPyTVZ+taT92+MkQqDr6-GzAAAMRtbD7PaUzHinBGEQXBRA4cWkRd6E1tHcgbYzSEZ7dGXVqZJ+lTew29AA==) (36 days ago)

Could it really be one of these? Or something even further back? The most recent Windows Defender update for `Skeeyah.A!bit` came out two months ago, so it should have infected me no more than two days back when I got the alert, right? Could I have contracted the trojan via some Windows 10 vulnerability? I should note that my other family members use standard Windows accounts, only I have administrator rights. Thanks for shedding some light on this, I'm totally clueless!

Comment: You're linking directly to these exes and installers. Why? Would you like us to install them and see if we get it, too? I would accept links to the pages where you got them from but not the exes themselves.

Comment: @Octopus: Srsly? IE will warn you and n00bs like you if you accidentally click the link. (If you're more advanced than that I'm sure you can find the pages in five seconds using the so-called search engine called "google.")

Comment: Jonas, chill out a bit there champ.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf: Sorry, but when it started out, stackexchange used to be about asking serious questions in search of intelligent answers and there were hardly any cheesy knuckleheads about questioning the details. It was all about helping each other understand. "Why link directly to .exe's" is not helpful in the slightest. I've been here 6x longer than you and feel the original intent often gets lost these days. Does that make sense to you, or do you think I'm just a grumpy chump?

Comment: No, I think you're being a "grumpy chump". The comments are for questions and clarifications, not answers. Octopus' comment was just that; a comment, and you blew it WAY out of proportion.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf: you're probably right. Accusing me of wanting others to contract the virus was harsh to me though. And as such it still feels right to drub the authoritarian that have no authority.

Answer (score -1):

Any website could have been infected by malware and when you entered into one of those there was a silent download that infected you. Simply as that. It could be that you had a port open and someone scanned it and sent malware through it. You could have been infected before, or some of the devices into your same network could have been infected.
The other pcs in your network could be infected or any usbs. 
By the way... windows defender wont do much to help you... you better start using better security measures.